# Grub boot loader Macbook Pro

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, macbook

I am using macbook pro 2012, i wanted single boot macbook  burned ubuntu iso to Sandisk USB drive everything was okay. Reseted hard drive, made partitions manually, also kept 512 MB free space for EFI. At the END of installation i got error mesage :” Error: grub loader not installed”. As you know macbook pro doesnt have BIOS settings key to force linux start. After finished installation ejected usb drive and restared system but nothing appears. Just white screen with “?” I am so confused.please help me

Comment: Please be specific with details; by *latest* ISO do you mean the 2022-October release (ie. 22.10), but if so which?  Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop? Ubuntu 22.10 Server? or a *flavor*. Depending on how you *burn* the ISO to USB/flash media; you can create a system that will not boot on specific hardware (but boot on others, ie. *burn* it so it's BIOS/legacy only, or uEFI only, etc) but you didn't mention how (*if burnt incorrectly a lack of grub boot loader write is what you can get but it's not the only reason*)  Did you write the ISO as per Ubuntu's apple mac documentation?

Comment: Yed i did exactly

Comment: **I can execute terminal which usb installer